# Facebook Canvas Page Like/Non-Like Content

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml

I would like to have my canvas page on facebook display different content for visitors that have liked and not liked yet.

I ran across this article but it uses FBML:
[Facebook "Like" to see canvas page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586020/facebook-like-to-see-canvas-page)

It's my understading that facebook is phasing out FMBL support.

Does anyone know how to do this without using FBML?
Example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a fan / like gate on Facebook?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8560385/how-to-create-a-fan-like-gate-on-facebook)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if user liked page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. This probably won't matter since they're making everyone go to a timeline, the fangated pages are pretty much going away.